# Primitive element theorem: an example

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In the proof of primitive element theorem, especially when base field $F$ is infinite, the arguments goes as follows.

Let $E$ be a finite separable extension of $F$ and consider $\alpha,\beta\in E$; they are algebraic over $F$. One want to show that $F(\alpha,\beta)=F(\gamma)$ for some (primitive) element $\gamma$.

Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+ \cdots + a_nx^n$ and $g(x)=b_0+b_1x+ \cdots + b_mx^m$ be irreducible polynomials of $\alpha,\beta$ over $F$ respectively.

Let $\alpha=\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$ and $\beta=\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_m$ be all the distinct roots of $f$ and $g$ respectively.

Choose $c\in F$ such that $\alpha+c\beta\neq \alpha_i+c\beta_j$ for all $i,j$ (except $i=1$, $j=1$).

Then $\gamma:=\alpha+c\beta$ (turns out to be) required primitive element of $F(\alpha,\beta)$.

**Question:** Can one illustrate with example, that how $\alpha+c\beta$ can be equal to $\alpha_i+c\beta_j$ for non-zero $c\in F$? (I would like to see a non-trivial example, not like $\alpha=\sqrt{-1}$ and $\beta=2\sqrt{-1}$).

Comment: I really don't know what you count as nontrivial: how about taking for the $\alpha$s the four roots of $X^4+1$ and for the $\beta$s the two roots of $2X^2-1$? [There are coincidences in the $\alpha+\beta$s.]